# The LaTex-TexMaker does not launch normally nor does it build a pdf out put. What is the solution?

Tags: texmaker

LaTex-Texmaker does not launch (start) normally. I have to press shift+ctrl+F11 to begin processing. Nor does it build a PDF output. It just says, "process exited with emergency error"
This (below) is my Preamble. I was supposed to complete my Ph.D. Thesis, but I could not as I got stuck with such problems. I kindly request your usaul help to assist me.

Note: I posted the same problem last time. I am aking now as the problme was not solved and I do not know what to do nor do I have anyone who knows how to fix this problem. Please hel. Thanks so much for your kind assistance in advance.

```
%\documentclass[english]{article}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}llllllll
\usepackage{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{blkarray, tabularx, longtable, multirow,threeparttable, makecell, booktabs, hhline, caption}
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
% \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % default is 6pt
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% to make heads of table in BOLD, it is used with booktabs package and \head
%\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm} % needed for command eqref or Math packages
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{makeidx} % needed for creating an index
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passage
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,
                    labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize, sc},
                      labelsep=newline,
                      justification=centering}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

%% page settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border stteings
\parindent=0cm % for spece of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hypenless justification (tries to)
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliograph style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
   ,breaklinks
   %, ngerman
    ] {hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the docuent, the option colorlink=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonk links (list of figures), and the ngerman sets everything for german s default hyperlink languages.
\definecolor {c1}{rgb}{0,0, 1} % blue
\definecolor {c2}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % light blue
\definecolor {c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}
\usepackage{cleveref}%% to be loaded after hyperref
%\parindent 0ex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead {}
\frenchspacing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}%This affects the in spacing of my paragraphs
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{Section_1}
%\input{Section_2}
%\input{Section_3}
%\input{Section_4}
%\input{Section_5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{plain}
\Large {\textbf{ MULTIDIMENSIONAL POVERTY INDEX\\ IN ETHIOPIA (2011/12): ROBUSTNESS TEST,\\ DECOMPOSITION, AND MAPPING }}\\
%\Large{\textbf{Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}\\

\vfill
\line(1,0){400}\\ [1mm]%automatically putting vetical space btween the two elments to fill the page
\huge{\textbf{A Ph.D. Thesis:\\ University of KwaZulu-Natal\\ School of Accounting, Economics and Finance\\ Department of Economics }}\\[3mm]
%\lipsum[1]
%{\setstretch{1.0}\color{blue}
%\lipsum[2]
%}
%\lipsum[3]
%\Large{\textbf{-This is a sample subtitle-}}\\[1mm]
\line(1,0){400}\\
\vfill    %Now it is centered at the page
By WELDESLASSIE HAILAI\\
Candidate\#:{214585063}\\
Supervisor Dr. Claire Vermaak\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\date {\today}
%\maketitle
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} %This helps you to remove the page # in the table of contents part
\clearpage
%\chapter{Background and Justification}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark}
%\fancyhead[EC]{\rightmark}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} % needed to add a line at the bottom
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1} %Now the f
%\chapter{doc one}
%\input{document_1_body}
%\chapter{doc two}
%\input{document_2_body}
%\chapter{doc three}
%\input{document_3_body}
\section{Background and Justifications}

\subsection{Introduction:Why  Multidimensional Poverty Index(MPI)?}  
There is a synchronization of thoughts in broad literature in the study of well-being and/or poverty measurement study and analysis practice that well-being is multidimensional and the overlapping deprivation and destitution that a poor person suffer should be studied in a multidimensional perspective(Alkire and Foster, 2011; Alkire et al.,2015; Sen, 1985; Atkinson, 2003; Ferreira and Lugo, 2013.\\
According to Decancq et al.,(2014), even those that are suitably deflated prices for temporal and geographical differences in the uni-dimensional poverty measurement approach using income or consumption do not qualify as good proxies for two main reasons. They argue that individuals may suffer from rationing since private goods market as well as labor markets may fail to be competitive. Moreover, some essential social and public goods such as education, health, and security services may not be private and marketable. \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Fix the typo that @samcarter mentioned in the answer. (2) Are you sure the code you posted above gives you an error? It compiles well for me (after fixing the typo). (3) If yes, show the log file. Use `pastebin.com` if need be.

Comment: @leandriis, Thanks, 1. I corrected the typo and it was not in the original document. 2. Yes. the texmaker does not compile the above codes nor does it launch normally 3. Can you please extend your explanation on this "Use pastebin.com" to enlighten me on how to use it. I did not understand it correctly

Comment: @Troy, Please assist me how to fix this problem (stated above) as I am very much stressed and becoming crazy due to such issues as I am missing the deadline for submission.

Comment: (1) You still have not corrected the typo in your question. Click edit below your question and make the correction. (2) Go to https://pastebin.com/ and paste in your log file after compiling the code above. Share the pastebin link here.

Comment: @Troy Dear Troy, I am still waiting for your kind assistance.  I could not proceed with my research work and I do not know how to fix this problem. Please, Please do help me. Thanks

Comment: I asked for the log file, you still have not provided it.

Comment: @Troy Big apologies, it is because I did not understand what you mean by the log file. Is it the whole work and how can I send it to you. It's more than 250 pages.

Comment: After compilation, look at the folder that contains your `.tex` file. There should be a `.log` file (which is just a text document). For example, https://imgur.com/a/9wP1l42. It should read something like `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6670 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.5.3)  4 MAY 2018 09:44` at the beginning. Copy the contents into [pastebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com) and share the link with us.

Comment: If you don't understand these instructions, I would recommend finding someone else who is more computer literate to help out. (I mean hands-on help, not online help via text). I'm really sorry, I don't have the time to walk you through this step by step. If this is your PhD, ask your advisors/prof/anyone else in your University who have experience in LaTeX.

Comment: @Troy Thanks so much for your great help. I think I got you now and I copied and shared log file as per your kind instruction. Did you get it? Unfortunately, my supervisor is good at computational software like PSPP Stata, SAS and so forth but has no idea on LaTex and that is why I am bothering you as you are the only person I can ask for assistance and this community is the only contact I have to request for some help.

Comment: You need to share the pastebin link here..

Comment: @Troy I shared the do file in pastebin.com as it's too long and I cannot share it here. Maybe there some techincal issues on how to share the do file here that I did not understand.

Comment: @Troy Is this correct? https://pastebin.com/3Sm8ZSdb

Comment: That is **not** the log file from compiling the code in your question.

Comment: @Troy what about this https://pastebin.com/JhqEqWEG?

Comment: No sorry, you still don't get it. Get help from someone from your University.

Comment: @Troy I am sharing you the whole my research work as I am in a deep anxiety and I cannot focus on. I hope this works https://pastebin.com/CmSYHL0g. I am so sorry that I am bothering you and sharing your precious time. However, I do not have any other option (I asked in the Mathematics Department and Physics Department ) in my University. But there is no viable solution and no one can help me to fix this problem. It's more than three weeks since this work is stuck and I will simply wait for your assistance when you have time. Thanks and God bless

Comment: @Troy is the last link correct?

Comment: @Troy This is definitely the correct one https://pastebin.com/C6EWrkfP and it seems that I am progressing though it still needs some improvement. I have been doing it by myself through reading, watching youtube tutorial and trial and error practical testing. Thanks